# Computing the homology of $|Y.|$ for a (semi)simplicial set Y.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Say $Y_{\bullet}$ is a semisimplicial set with $Y_1$ a finite set of cardinality $N$, and $Y_0$ a single point $\{*\}$ (and $Y_n = \emptyset$ for all $n \geq 2$).

I'm trying to visualize what $|Y_{\bullet}|$ actually looks like for a given $N$. Also, how can I compute the homology of $|Y_{\bullet}|$?

For starters, isn't $H_0(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What? If $Y_0$ is a singleton, there's no chance of $|Y_{\bullet}|$ having more than one component. So $H_0 (Y)$ can't be $\mathbb{Z}^N$ for any $N > 1$.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. I've edited my prompt.

Answer (score 3):

For the semi-simplicial set $Y_{\bullet}$ you describe, $| Y_{\bullet} |$ is the topological space obtained by adjoining $N$ loops to a point. (For example, $N = 0$ yields a point, $N = 1$ yields the circle, and $N = 2$ yields a figure 8.) Note that there is only one possible choice for the face operators!

The homology of this space is quite easy to describe: $H_0$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, $H_1$ is $\mathbb{Z}^N$, and $H_n$ is trivial for $n > 1$. This agrees with the homology of the chain complex associated with the free semisimplicial abelian group generated by $Y_{\bullet}$.

In fact, even the homotopy groups are easy to describe: $\pi_1$ is the free group on $N$ generators, and $\pi_n$ is trivial for $n > 1$. This is because the universal cover is contractible.